# Positioning iframe element relative to object

Tags: iframe, css-position

So i'm trying to add a like button to my wordpress blog's homepage, where i am showing excerpts instead of full posts. A thumbnail image is displayed next to each excerpt.

These images are not consistent in size, so the like button's location varies. How do i position the like button to be displayed below the image no matter its size?

You can see my current status on http://wordsandmusic.me

Ive seen several solutions to this on the forums, but unfortunately know nothing about coding and this may be way beyond my capacities. Still, if someone can help it would make just a little bit happier :) This problem has become one of those must-be-conquered things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i see you have `<div class="entry-summary"></div>` above the iframe that contains your like button.

Then you could just go to the file `styles.css`, search and add the line of code i'm pointing:

```css
.entry-content, .entry-summary {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block; /* ADD THIS LINE */
    height: auto;
    padding: 12px 0 0;
}
```

and you're done!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply.

Im working with a child theme, so my css file only includes changes ive made, which override existing functions in the parents stylesheet.

Ive added the code youve described, but i dont think its overriding the parent.

Comment: I should add that this is not a caching issue

Comment: Ok the file you need to modify is at `http://wordsandmusic.me/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css` directly (if you wish) it should work. If you want to override in the child then point me to your overriding file or simply copy the entire code to your overriding file (which i think it's Bastard Test, i just took a quick look). Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes, changing the css of the parent theme (twentyten) does indeed make the desired change. This change will be overwritten whenever an update is made to the theme.

My child theme is indeed bastard test, and contains a style.css file with an import command, pointing at the parents theme style.css file. And styling added here will override the parent theme, according to css hierarchy.

Ive managed to override using an !important, though from my reading i understand this is not the best solution. Still, this works just fine for now. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome... as this was not a fully answer to your need can you provided and upvote to the answer? regards...

Comment: im not sure i understand what you mean

Comment: you see a score marker at the left side of my answer? just click the up arrow, this way it indicates that my answer was useful to you...

Comment: it wont let me do that because i have a low rating. ive marked it as accepted. Hope that helps.

Thanks again.

Comment: So it turns out adding the inblock line caused some of my posts to be cut off on the side. I have now removed the line, and the buttons are once again out of alignment.

Comment: don't get it... can you provide a way so i can see what's going on? this way i might be able to help you better...

Comment: Ive removed that version from the site, but have uploaded a screenshot here: http://wordsandmusic.me/wp-content/uploads/General/cutoff.jpg

You can see the text cut off on the left side.